# Strange error in my table

Tags: tables, errors

I need help with an error:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccp{8cm}@{}}
\toprule
Valor DOP & Calificación & Descripción \\
\cmidrule(c){1-1}\cmidrule(c){2-2}\cmidrule(p){3-3}
<1 & Ideal & Este es el mayor nivel posible, para aquellas aplicaciones que requieren el mayor nivel de precisión en todo momento \\
1-2 & Excelente & A este nivel, las medidas de posicionamiento se consideran lo suficientemente precisas para la mayor parte de las aplicaciones de precisión\\
2-5 & Bueno & Representa el mínimo nivel para tomar decisiones de navegación en ruta\\
5-10 & Moderado & Las medidas de posicionamiento pueden utilizarse para hacer cálculos, pero la calidad debe mejorarse. Este nivel (e inferiores) suelen aparecer al no encontrarse en condiciones de cielo abierto\\
10-20 & Razonable & Representa un nivel bajo de confianza. Estas medidas deben descartarse o emplearse únicamente para hacer estimaciones de la posición donde se requiera poca precisión\\
>20 & Pobre & A este nivel las medidas pueden presentar imprecisiones de hasta 300 metros, con lo que deben ser descartadas\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Significado de los valores DOP}
\label{fig:doptable}
\end{table}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined control sequence. <argument>
  ...al \expandafter \let \cmrsideswitch \@tempa \fi \fi
1.227 \cmidrule(c){1-1} \cmidrule(c){2}\cmidrule(p){3-3}
```

Comment: Please turn this into a complete compilable document (with `\documentclass{}` and the smallest number of packages needed to show the error (presumably `booktabs`.)  See [Minimal Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of `\cmidrule` for trimming can be a combination of `l` (trim left) or `r` (trim right) or `r{<length>}`, `l{<length>}`; so you could use something like

```
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
```

Here's the complete example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccp{8cm}@{}}
\toprule
Valor DOP & Calificación & Descripción \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
$<1$ & Ideal & Este es el mayor nivel posible, para aquellas aplicaciones que requieren el mayor nivel de precisión en todo momento \\
1-2 & Excelente & A este nivel, las medidas de posicionamiento se consideran lo suficientemente precisas para la mayor parte de las aplicaciones de precisión\\
2-5 & Bueno & Representa el mínimo nivel para tomar decisiones de navegación en ruta\\
5-10 & Moderado & Las medidas de posicionamiento pueden utilizarse para hacer cálculos, pero la calidad debe mejorarse. Este nivel (e inferiores) suelen aparecer al no encontrarse en condiciones de cielo abierto\\
10-20 & Razonable & Representa un nivel bajo de confianza. Estas medidas deben descartarse o emplearse únicamente para hacer estimaciones de la posición donde se requiera poca precisión\\
>20 & Pobre & A este nivel las medidas pueden presentar imprecisiones de hasta 300 metros, con lo que deben ser descartadas\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Significado de los valores DOP}
\label{fig:doptable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Nothe the use of math mode in `$<1$`. (Of course, `inputenc` will have to be loaded with an appropriate encoding).