# Weird Error from \midrule

Tags: tables, errors, longtable

I am getting a weird error code:

```
\expandafter \let \cmrsideswitch \@tempa \fi \fi?
```

[Strange error in my table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38080/strange-error-in-my-table)

The question above had the same code and it was liked to his use of `\cmidrule`.
I am using `\midrule` but can't seem to figure out how to solve my problem from the question above.

Example shown below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}  % first of the commands relating to page formatting that were not included in the original question
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}  
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}    %20pt
\def\refhgb{\hangindent=10pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % last of commands not included in original question

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{clcccccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{10}{c}{Simulation Results for n=30} \\
& & & & & & {$\sigma^2$} \\
\cline{3-10}
($\rho_1$, $\rho_2$) & Estimator & 0.0001 & 0.25 & 1 & 25 & 50 & 75 & 100 & 400 \\
\midrule
(0.99,0.99)              & HK          &1.000 &0.587    &0.564  &0.551  &0.557  &0.559  &0.559  &0.558\\
                         & HKB         &0.998   &0.354  &0.311  &0.277  &0.282  &0.283  &0.283  &0.280\\ 
                         & LW          &1.000   &0.415  &0.179  &0.011  &0.005  &0.003  &0.002  &0.001\\
                         & ICOMP       &0.873   &0.469  &0.450  &0.415  &0.423  &0.426  &0.426  &0.421\\
                         & S           &0.873   &0.309  &0.133  &0.009  &0.004  &0.003  &0.002  &0.001\\
                         & GM          &0.651   &0.176  &0.146  &0.068  &0.059  &0.053  &0.050  &0.040\\
                         & AM                &52.214    &0.131  &0.086  &0.010  &0.006  &0.004  &0.003  &0.002\\
                         & MED         &0.688   &0.265  &0.181  &0.130  &0.131  &0.130  &0.130  &0.128\\
                         & JRR         &1.000   &0.673  &0.613  &0.563  &0.569  &0.570  &0.570  &0.567\\
                         & URR         &0.431   &0.176  &0.178  &0.170  &0.177  &0.180  &0.179  &0.174\\
                         & PCR         &0.973   &0.807  &0.811  &0.806  &0.809  &0.810  &0.809  &0.811\\
                         & PCR CI      &0.476   &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001\\
                         & R-K         &2.132   &0.178  &0.178  &0.170  &0.177  &0.180  &0.179  &0.174\\
                         & R-K CI      &2.170   &0.003  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001\\
                         & MCRR        &0.439   &0.170  &0.172  &0.165  &0.172  &0.174  &0.173  &0.168\\
                         & MCRR CI     &0.476   &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001\\
                         & LRRE        &0.465   &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001  &0.001\\
                         & LRRE MSE    &0.645   &0.486  &0.486  &0.478  &0.485  &0.487  &0.487  &0.486\\
                         & OIRE        &1.479   &0.294  &0.145  &0.149  &0.162  &0.164  &0.163  &0.159\\
                         & OIRE MSE    &1.587   &0.097  &0.072  &0.137  &0.153  &0.156  &0.155  &0.152\\
                         & GIREI       &1.000   &0.902  &0.998  &0.480  &0.389  &0.346  &0.317  &0.261\\
                         & GIREI MSE   &1.000   &0.703  &0.600  &0.373  &0.325  &0.299  &0.279  &0.239\\
                         & GIREII      &1.029   &0.487  &0.359  &0.233  &0.239  &0.237  &0.231  &0.216\\
                         & GIREII MSE  &1.046   &0.438  &0.305  &0.187  &0.193  &0.192  &0.189  &0.179\\
\midrule   
(0.99,0.1)               & HK          &1.000   &0.59       &0.541  &0.525  &0.52       &0.523  &0.522  &0.521\\
                         & HKB         &0.998   &0.320  &0.257  &0.218  &0.212  &0.214  &0.212  &0.212\\ 
                         & LW          &0.999   &0.369  &0.154  &0.020  &0.014  &0.012  &0.011  &0.009\\
                         & ICOMP       &0.892   &0.100  &0.089  &0.085  &0.083  &0.086  &0.084  &0.086\\
                         & S           &0.892   &0.088  &0.058  &0.015  &0.012  &0.011  &0.010  &0.009\\
                         & GM          &0.728   &0.062  &0.043  &0.020  &0.018  &0.016  &0.016  &0.014\\
                         & AM          &101.610 &0.373  &0.142  &0.016  &0.010  &0.007  &0.006  &0.004\\
                         & MED         &0.772   &0.196  &0.118  &0.020  &0.016  &0.014  &0.013  &0.012\\
                         & JRR         &1.000   &0.633  &0.533  &0.463  &0.454  &0.457  &0.455  &0.454\\
                         & URR         &0.988   &0.162  &0.151  &0.149  &0.145  &0.147  &0.146  &0.146\\
                         & PCR         &0.944   &0.813  &0.816  &0.817  &0.809  &0.811  &0.814  &0.812\\
                         & PCR CI      &0.474   &0.022  &0.022  &0.022  &0.022  &0.021  &0.022  &0.022\\
                         & R-K         &0.933   &0.163  &0.151  &0.148  &0.144  &0.146  &0.145  &0.145\\
                         & R-K CI      &0.474   &0.025  &0.020  &0.017  &0.017  &0.017  &0.017  &0.017\\
                         & MCRR        &0.934   &0.156  &0.147  &0.146  &0.141  &0.144  &0.143  &0.143\\
                         & MCRR CI     &0.474   &0.023  &0.020  &0.018  &0.018  &0.017  &0.017  &0.017\\
                         & LRRE        &0.472   &0.007  &0.007  &0.008  &0.007  &0.007  &0.006  &0.006\\
                         & LRRE MSE    &0.639   &0.488  &0.490  &0.491  &0.486  &0.489  &0.487  &0.485\\
                         & OIRE        &0.845   &0.055  &0.103  &0.158  &0.154  &0.156  &0.153  &0.150\\
                         & OIRE MSE    &1.031   &0.038  &0.085  &0.152  &0.148  &0.150  &0.147  &0.144\\
                         & GIREI       &1.000   &0.974  &0.961  &0.360  &0.302  &0.280  &0.265  &0.236\\
                         & GIREI MSE   &1.000   &0.539  &0.485  &0.292  &0.262  &0.249  &0.238  &0.219\\
                         & GIREII      &0.853   &0.213  &0.160  &0.143  &0.137  &0.138  &0.133  &0.131\\
                         & GIREII MSE  &0.792   &0.192  &0.156  &0.138  &0.131  &0.132  &0.127  &0.126\\
\midrule       
(0.9,0.9)                & HK          &1.000   &0.874  &0.709  &0.568  &0.564  &0.562  &0.564  &0.561\\
                         & HKB         &1.000   &0.649  &0.475  &0.300  &0.292  &0.289  &0.291  &0.285\\ 
                         & LW          &1.000   &0.861  &0.654  &0.102  &0.070  &0.059  &0.054  &0.043\\
                         & ICOMP       &0.998   &0.640  &0.594  &0.545  &0.543  &0.542  &0.545  &0.540\\
                         & S           &0.998   &0.639  &0.539  &0.096  &0.068  &0.058  &0.054  &0.043\\
                         & GM          &0.996   &0.306  &0.244  &0.113  &0.099  &0.091  &0.087  &0.074\\
                         & AM          &1.024   &0.811  &0.380  &0.065  &0.044  &0.035  &0.031  &0.021\\
                         & MED         &0.998   &0.361  &0.324  &0.145  &0.136  &0.133  &0.133  &0.129\\
                         & JRR         &1.000   &0.919  &0.790  &0.593  &0.582  &0.578  &0.580  &0.573\\
                         & URR         &1.014   &0.197  &0.187  &0.182  &0.181  &0.181  &0.183  &0.179\\
                         & PCR         &1.000   &0.828  &0.817  &0.813  &0.812  &0.812  &0.815  &0.814\\
                         & PCR CI      &1.000   &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000\\
                         & R-K         &1.018   &0.275  &0.217  &0.183  &0.180  &0.180  &0.183  &0.178\\
                         & R-K CI      &1.018   &0.275  &0.217  &0.183  &0.180  &0.180  &0.183  &0.178\\
                         & MCRR        &1.014   &0.193  &0.182  &0.177  &0.176  &0.176  &0.179  &0.174\\
                         & MCRR CI     &1.014   &0.197  &0.187  &0.182  &0.181  &0.181  &0.183  &0.179\\
                         & LRRE        &8.418   &0.053  &0.032  &0.021  &0.019  &0.019  &0.018  &0.016\\
                         & LRRE MSE    &1.064   &0.502  &0.493  &0.493  &0.491  &0.491  &0.493  &0.489\\
                         & OIRE        &0.999   &0.229  &0.236  &0.218  &0.205  &0.200  &0.201  &0.189\\
                         & OIRE MSE    &0.998   &0.182  &0.207  &0.208  &0.197  &0.193  &0.194  &0.183\\
                         & GIREI       &1.000   &0.932  &1.008  &0.428  &0.344  &0.310  &0.294  &0.248\\
                         & GIREI MSE   &1.000   &0.633  &0.586  &0.350  &0.298  &0.274  &0.266  &0.230\\
                         & GIREII      &0.978   &0.449  &0.376  &0.297  &0.271  &0.258  &0.254  &0.231\\
                         & GIREII MSE  &0.976   &0.450  &0.379  &0.268  &0.245  &0.235  &0.232  &0.212\\
\midrule              
(0.9,0.1)                & HK          &1.000   &0.905  &0.759  &0.576  &0.565  &0.564  &0.563  &0.566\\
                         & HKB         &1.000   &0.706  &0.521  &0.304  &0.289  &0.286  &0.283  &0.281\\ 
                         & LW          &1.000   &0.842  &0.630  &0.156  &0.125  &0.115  &0.107  &0.095\\
                         & ICOMP       &0.999   &0.539  &0.453  &0.366  &0.356  &0.356  &0.355  &0.355\\
                         & S           &0.999   &0.538  &0.440  &0.147  &0.121  &0.114  &0.106  &0.095\\
                         & GM          &0.998   &0.484  &0.316  &0.117  &0.100  &0.093  &0.088  &0.077\\
                         & AM          &56.142  &2.452  &1.063  &0.116  &0.072  &0.057  &0.049  &0.034\\
                         & MED         &0.998   &0.628  &0.412  &0.135  &0.113  &0.108  &0.102  &0.092\\
                         & JRR         &1.000   &0.937  &0.804  &0.564  &0.546  &0.543  &0.540  &0.537\\
                         & URR         &1.000   &0.537  &0.406  &0.231  &0.219  &0.218  &0.216  &0.214\\
                         & PCR         &1.064   &0.847  &0.828  &0.818  &0.818  &0.818  &0.818  &0.819\\
                         & PCR CI      &1.000   &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000\\
                         & R-K         &1.063   &0.491  &0.370  &0.210  &0.198  &0.197  &0.195  &0.194\\
                         & R-K CI      &0.999   &0.498  &0.372  &0.210  &0.198  &0.197  &0.195  &0.194\\
                         & MCRR        &1.063   &0.481  &0.346  &0.216  &0.206  &0.206  &0.204  &0.201\\
                         & MCRR CI     &1.000   &0.537  &0.406  &0.231  &0.219  &0.218  &0.216  &0.214\\
                         & LRRE        &2.626   &0.112  &0.083  &0.069  &0.064  &0.064  &0.062  &0.057\\
                         & LRRE MSE    &1.094   &0.527  &0.504  &0.497  &0.492  &0.491  &0.490  &0.491 \\
                         & OIRE        &96.090  &0.266  &0.425  &0.242  &0.216  &0.210  &0.204  &0.197\\
                         & OIRE MSE    &51.462  &0.224  &0.298  &0.228  &0.207  &0.203  &0.198  &0.192\\
                         & GIREI       &1.001   &1.165  &1.080  &0.396  &0.323  &0.294  &0.278  &0.248\\
                         & GIREI MSE   &1.000   &0.652  &0.583  &0.324  &0.281  &0.262  &0.252  &0.231\\
                         & GIREII      &2.356   &0.750  &0.445  &0.275  &0.247  &0.238  &0.232  &0.221\\
                         & GIREII MSE  &2.897   &0.510  &0.356  &0.257  &0.233  &0.226  &0.220  &0.210\\
\midrule   
(0.7,0.3)                & HK         &1.000    &0.959  &0.875  &0.597  &0.585  &0.579  &0.578  &0.572 \\
                         & HKB         &1.000   &0.842  &0.678  &0.347  &0.327  &0.318  &0.315  &0.306\\ 
                         & LW          &1.000   &0.922  &0.790  &0.273  &0.232  &0.215  &0.208  &0.190\\
                         & ICOMP       &1.000   &0.833  &0.746  &0.606  &0.598  &0.594  &0.593  &0.589\\
                         & S           &1.000   &0.833  &0.732  &0.270  &0.231  &0.215  &0.208  &0.190\\
                         & GM          &1.036   &1.325  &0.750  &0.192  &0.154  &0.139  &0.132  &0.116\\
                         & AM          &2043.436    &6.822  &2.632  &0.244  &0.138  &0.104  &0.088  &0.062\\
                         & MED         &1.014   &1.741  &0.883  &0.233  &0.190  &0.176  &0.168  &0.152\\
                         & JRR         &1.000   &0.982  &0.912  &0.627  &0.608  &0.599  &0.596  &0.587\\
                         & URR         &1.000   &0.725  &0.515  &0.250  &0.236  &0.231  &0.231  &0.229\\
                         & PCR         &1.021   &0.847  &0.827  &0.829  &0.829  &0.829  &0.827  &0.822\\
                         & PCR CI      &1.000   &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000  &1.000\\
                         & R-K         &1.020   &0.741  &0.647  &0.234  &0.213  &0.205  &0.202  &0.196\\
                         & R-K CI      &1.000   &0.748  &0.649  &0.234  &0.213  &0.205  &0.202  &0.196\\
                         & MCRR        &1.021   &0.577  &0.422  &0.240  &0.228  &0.223  &0.223  &0.218\\
                         & MCRR CI     &1.000   &0.725  &0.515  &0.250  &0.236  &0.231  &0.231  &0.229\\
                         & LRRE        &1.993   &0.179  &0.157  &0.143  &0.134  &0.129  &0.127  &0.121\\
                         & LRRE MSE    &1.042   &0.535  &0.519  &0.514  &0.510  &0.504  &0.502  &0.493\\
                         & OIRE        &5.249   &1.009  &0.916  &0.316  &0.272  &0.251  &0.243  &0.217\\
                         & OIRE MSE    &5.249   &0.542  &0.424  &0.286  &0.259  &0.243  &0.237  &0.213\\
                         & GIREI       &1.000   &1.058  &1.022  &0.407  &0.341  &0.305  &0.290  &0.253\\
                         & GIREI MSE   &1.000   &0.649  &0.603  &0.355  &0.309  &0.280  &0.270  &0.238\\
                         & GIREII      &5.432   &0.774  &0.521  &0.361  &0.322  &0.298  &0.286  &0.250\\
                         & GIREII MSE  &4.496   &0.562  &0.422  &0.341  &0.308  &0.285  &0.275  &0.240\\                                                               
\bottomrule
\caption{Simulation Results for Population Size 30}
\end{longtable}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated to the error but `n=30` should be `$n=30$` and the numbers in the columns would be better right aligned or in a decimal aligned column from `dcolumn` or `siunitx` packages, so that they were aligned on the decimal point rather than centred which currently pushes entries such as `52.214 ` out of alignment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I would typeset the table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[tableposition = top]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}  
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\def\refhg{\hangindent=20pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refhgb{\hangindent=10pt\hangafter=1}
\def\refmark{\par\vskip 2mm\noindent\refhg}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5.69pt} % distance between columns in table

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{
       c
       l
       S[table-format = 4.3]
  *{7}{S[table-format = 1.3]}
}
\caption{Simulation Results for Population Size~$n = 30$.} \\
 \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\sigma^{2}$} \\
 \cline{3-10}
  $(\rho_{1},\rho_{2})$ & \mc{Estimator} &   {0.0001} & {0.25} & {1}     & {25}    & {50}    & {75}     & {100}    & {400}    \\
 \midrule
  $(0.99,0.99)$         & HK             &    1.000   &  0.587 &  0.564  &   0.551 &   0.557 &   0.559  &    0.559 &    0.558 \\
                        & HKB            &    0.998   &  0.354 &  0.311  &   0.277 &   0.282 &   0.283  &    0.283 &    0.280 \\
                        & LW             &    1.000   &  0.415 &  0.179  &   0.011 &   0.005 &   0.003  &    0.002 &    0.001 \\
                        & ICOMP          &    0.873   &  0.469 &  0.450  &   0.415 &   0.423 &   0.426  &    0.426 &    0.421 \\
                        & S              &    0.873   &  0.309 &  0.133  &   0.009 &   0.004 &   0.003  &    0.002 &    0.001 \\
                        & GM             &    0.651   &  0.176 &  0.146  &   0.068 &   0.059 &   0.053  &    0.050 &    0.040 \\
                        & AM             &   52.214   &  0.131 &  0.086  &   0.010 &   0.006 &   0.004  &    0.003 &    0.002 \\
                        & MED            &    0.688   &  0.265 &  0.181  &   0.130 &   0.131 &   0.130  &    0.130 &    0.128 \\
                        & JRR            &    1.000   &  0.673 &  0.613  &   0.563 &   0.569 &   0.570  &    0.570 &    0.567 \\
                        & URR            &    0.431   &  0.176 &  0.178  &   0.170 &   0.177 &   0.180  &    0.179 &    0.174 \\
                        & PCR            &    0.973   &  0.807 &  0.811  &   0.806 &   0.809 &   0.810  &    0.809 &    0.811 \\
                        & PCR CI         &    0.476   &  0.001 &  0.001  &   0.001 &   0.001 &   0.001  &    0.001 &    0.001 \\
                        & R-K            &    2.132   &  0.178 &  0.178  &   0.170 &   0.177 &   0.180  &    0.179 &    0.174 \\
                        & R-K CI         &    2.170   &  0.003 &  0.001  &   0.001 &   0.001 &   0.001  &    0.001 &    0.001 \\
                        & MCRR           &    0.439   &  0.170 &  0.172  &   0.165 &   0.172 &   0.174  &    0.173 &    0.168 \\
                        & MCRR CI        &    0.476   &  0.001 &  0.001  &   0.001 &   0.001 &   0.001  &    0.001 &    0.001 \\
                        & LRRE           &    0.465   &  0.001 &  0.001  &   0.001 &   0.001 &   0.001  &    0.001 &    0.001 \\
                        & LRRE MSE       &    0.645   &  0.486 &  0.486  &   0.478 &   0.485 &   0.487  &    0.487 &    0.486 \\
                        & OIRE           &    1.479   &  0.294 &  0.145  &   0.149 &   0.162 &   0.164  &    0.163 &    0.159 \\
                        & OIRE MSE       &    1.587   &  0.097 &  0.072  &   0.137 &   0.153 &   0.156  &    0.155 &    0.152 \\
                        & GIREI          &    1.000   &  0.902 &  0.998  &   0.480 &   0.389 &   0.346  &    0.317 &    0.261 \\
                        & GIREI MSE      &    1.000   &  0.703 &  0.600  &   0.373 &   0.325 &   0.299  &    0.279 &    0.239 \\
                        & GIREII         &    1.029   &  0.487 &  0.359  &   0.233 &   0.239 &   0.237  &    0.231 &    0.216 \\
                        & GIREII MSE     &    1.046   &  0.438 &  0.305  &   0.187 &   0.193 &   0.192  &    0.189 &    0.179 \\
 \midrule
  $(0.99,0.1)$          & HK             &    1.000   &  0.59  &  0.541  &   0.525 &   0.52  &   0.523  &    0.522 &    0.521 \\
                        & HKB            &    0.998   &  0.320 &  0.257  &   0.218 &   0.212 &   0.214  &    0.212 &    0.212 \\
                        & LW             &    0.999   &  0.369 &  0.154  &   0.020 &   0.014 &   0.012  &    0.011 &    0.009 \\
                        & ICOMP          &    0.892   &  0.100 &  0.089  &   0.085 &   0.083 &   0.086  &    0.084 &    0.086 \\
                        & S              &    0.892   &  0.088 &  0.058  &   0.015 &   0.012 &   0.011  &    0.010 &    0.009 \\
                        & GM             &    0.728   &  0.062 &  0.043  &   0.020 &   0.018 &   0.016  &    0.016 &    0.014 \\
                        & AM             &  101.610   &  0.373 &  0.142  &   0.016 &   0.010 &   0.007  &    0.006 &    0.004 \\
                        & MED            &    0.772   &  0.196 &  0.118  &   0.020 &   0.016 &   0.014  &    0.013 &    0.012 \\
                        & JRR            &    1.000   &  0.633 &  0.533  &   0.463 &   0.454 &   0.457  &    0.455 &    0.454 \\
                        & URR            &    0.988   &  0.162 &  0.151  &   0.149 &   0.145 &   0.147  &    0.146 &    0.146 \\
                        & PCR            &    0.944   &  0.813 &  0.816  &   0.817 &   0.809 &   0.811  &    0.814 &    0.812 \\
                        & PCR CI         &    0.474   &  0.022 &  0.022  &   0.022 &   0.022 &   0.021  &    0.022 &    0.022 \\
                        & R-K            &    0.933   &  0.163 &  0.151  &   0.148 &   0.144 &   0.146  &    0.145 &    0.145 \\
                        & R-K CI         &    0.474   &  0.025 &  0.020  &   0.017 &   0.017 &   0.017  &    0.017 &    0.017 \\
                        & MCRR           &    0.934   &  0.156 &  0.147  &   0.146 &   0.141 &   0.144  &    0.143 &    0.143 \\
                        & MCRR CI        &    0.474   &  0.023 &  0.020  &   0.018 &   0.018 &   0.017  &    0.017 &    0.017 \\
                        & LRRE           &    0.472   &  0.007 &  0.007  &   0.008 &   0.007 &   0.007  &    0.006 &    0.006 \\
                        & LRRE MSE       &    0.639   &  0.488 &  0.490  &   0.491 &   0.486 &   0.489  &    0.487 &    0.485 \\
                        & OIRE           &    0.845   &  0.055 &  0.103  &   0.158 &   0.154 &   0.156  &    0.153 &    0.150 \\
                        & OIRE MSE       &    1.031   &  0.038 &  0.085  &   0.152 &   0.148 &   0.150  &    0.147 &    0.144 \\
                        & GIREI          &    1.000   &  0.974 &  0.961  &   0.360 &   0.302 &   0.280  &    0.265 &    0.236 \\
                        & GIREI MSE      &    1.000   &  0.539 &  0.485  &   0.292 &   0.262 &   0.249  &    0.238 &    0.219 \\
                        & GIREII         &    0.853   &  0.213 &  0.160  &   0.143 &   0.137 &   0.138  &    0.133 &    0.131 \\
                        & GIREII MSE     &    0.792   &  0.192 &  0.156  &   0.138 &   0.131 &   0.132  &    0.127 &    0.126 \\
 \midrule
  $(0.9,0.9)$           & HK             &    1.000   &  0.874 &  0.709  &   0.568 &   0.564 &   0.562  &    0.564 &    0.561 \\
                        & HKB            &    1.000   &  0.649 &  0.475  &   0.300 &   0.292 &   0.289  &    0.291 &    0.285 \\
                        & LW             &    1.000   &  0.861 &  0.654  &   0.102 &   0.070 &   0.059  &    0.054 &    0.043 \\
                        & ICOMP          &    0.998   &  0.640 &  0.594  &   0.545 &   0.543 &   0.542  &    0.545 &    0.540 \\
                        & S              &    0.998   &  0.639 &  0.539  &   0.096 &   0.068 &   0.058  &    0.054 &    0.043 \\
                        & GM             &    0.996   &  0.306 &  0.244  &   0.113 &   0.099 &   0.091  &    0.087 &    0.074 \\
                        & AM             &    1.024   &  0.811 &  0.380  &   0.065 &   0.044 &   0.035  &    0.031 &    0.021 \\
                        & MED            &    0.998   &  0.361 &  0.324  &   0.145 &   0.136 &   0.133  &    0.133 &    0.129 \\
                        & JRR            &    1.000   &  0.919 &  0.790  &   0.593 &   0.582 &   0.578  &    0.580 &    0.573 \\
                        & URR            &    1.014   &  0.197 &  0.187  &   0.182 &   0.181 &   0.181  &    0.183 &    0.179 \\
                        & PCR            &    1.000   &  0.828 &  0.817  &   0.813 &   0.812 &   0.812  &    0.815 &    0.814 \\
                        & PCR CI         &    1.000   &  1.000 &  1.000  &   1.000 &   1.000 &   1.000  &    1.000 &    1.000 \\
                        & R-K            &    1.018   &  0.275 &  0.217  &   0.183 &   0.180 &   0.180  &    0.183 &    0.178 \\
                        & R-K CI         &    1.018   &  0.275 &  0.217  &   0.183 &   0.180 &   0.180  &    0.183 &    0.178 \\
                        & MCRR           &    1.014   &  0.193 &  0.182  &   0.177 &   0.176 &   0.176  &    0.179 &    0.174 \\
                        & MCRR CI        &    1.014   &  0.197 &  0.187  &   0.182 &   0.181 &   0.181  &    0.183 &    0.179 \\
                        & LRRE           &    8.418   &  0.053 &  0.032  &   0.021 &   0.019 &   0.019  &    0.018 &    0.016 \\
                        & LRRE MSE       &    1.064   &  0.502 &  0.493  &   0.493 &   0.491 &   0.491  &    0.493 &    0.489 \\
                        & OIRE           &    0.999   &  0.229 &  0.236  &   0.218 &   0.205 &   0.200  &    0.201 &    0.189 \\
                        & OIRE MSE       &    0.998   &  0.182 &  0.207  &   0.208 &   0.197 &   0.193  &    0.194 &    0.183 \\
                        & GIREI          &    1.000   &  0.932 &  1.008  &   0.428 &   0.344 &   0.310  &    0.294 &    0.248 \\
                        & GIREI MSE      &    1.000   &  0.633 &  0.586  &   0.350 &   0.298 &   0.274  &    0.266 &    0.230 \\
                        & GIREII         &    0.978   &  0.449 &  0.376  &   0.297 &   0.271 &   0.258  &    0.254 &    0.231 \\
                        & GIREII MSE     &    0.976   &  0.450 &  0.379  &   0.268 &   0.245 &   0.235  &    0.232 &    0.212 \\
 \midrule
  $(0.9,0.1)$           & HK             &    1.000   &  0.905 &  0.759  &   0.576 &   0.565 &   0.564  &    0.563 &    0.566 \\
                        & HKB            &    1.000   &  0.706 &  0.521  &   0.304 &   0.289 &   0.286  &    0.283 &    0.281 \\
                        & LW             &    1.000   &  0.842 &  0.630  &   0.156 &   0.125 &   0.115  &    0.107 &    0.095 \\
                        & ICOMP          &    0.999   &  0.539 &  0.453  &   0.366 &   0.356 &   0.356  &    0.355 &    0.355 \\
                        & S              &    0.999   &  0.538 &  0.440  &   0.147 &   0.121 &   0.114  &    0.106 &    0.095 \\
                        & GM             &    0.998   &  0.484 &  0.316  &   0.117 &   0.100 &   0.093  &    0.088 &    0.077 \\
                        & AM             &   56.142   &  2.452 &  1.063  &   0.116 &   0.072 &   0.057  &    0.049 &    0.034 \\
                        & MED            &    0.998   &  0.628 &  0.412  &   0.135 &   0.113 &   0.108  &    0.102 &    0.092 \\
                        & JRR            &    1.000   &  0.937 &  0.804  &   0.564 &   0.546 &   0.543  &    0.540 &    0.537 \\
                        & URR            &    1.000   &  0.537 &  0.406  &   0.231 &   0.219 &   0.218  &    0.216 &    0.214 \\
                        & PCR            &    1.064   &  0.847 &  0.828  &   0.818 &   0.818 &   0.818  &    0.818 &    0.819 \\
                        & PCR CI         &    1.000   &  1.000 &  1.000  &   1.000 &   1.000 &   1.000  &    1.000 &    1.000 \\
                        & R-K            &    1.063   &  0.491 &  0.370  &   0.210 &   0.198 &   0.197  &    0.195 &    0.194 \\
                        & R-K CI         &    0.999   &  0.498 &  0.372  &   0.210 &   0.198 &   0.197  &    0.195 &    0.194 \\
                        & MCRR           &    1.063   &  0.481 &  0.346  &   0.216 &   0.206 &   0.206  &    0.204 &    0.201 \\
                        & MCRR CI        &    1.000   &  0.537 &  0.406  &   0.231 &   0.219 &   0.218  &    0.216 &    0.214 \\
                        & LRRE           &    2.626   &  0.112 &  0.083  &   0.069 &   0.064 &   0.064  &    0.062 &    0.057 \\
                        & LRRE MSE       &    1.094   &  0.527 &  0.504  &   0.497 &   0.492 &   0.491  &    0.490 &    0.491 \\
                        & OIRE           &   96.090   &  0.266 &  0.425  &   0.242 &   0.216 &   0.210  &    0.204 &    0.197 \\
                        & OIRE MSE       &   51.462   &  0.224 &  0.298  &   0.228 &   0.207 &   0.203  &    0.198 &    0.192 \\
                        & GIREI          &    1.001   &  1.165 &  1.080  &   0.396 &   0.323 &   0.294  &    0.278 &    0.248 \\
                        & GIREI MSE      &    1.000   &  0.652 &  0.583  &   0.324 &   0.281 &   0.262  &    0.252 &    0.231 \\
                        & GIREII         &    2.356   &  0.750 &  0.445  &   0.275 &   0.247 &   0.238  &    0.232 &    0.221 \\
                        & GIREII MSE     &    2.897   &  0.510 &  0.356  &   0.257 &   0.233 &   0.226  &    0.220 &    0.210 \\
 \midrule
  $(0.7,0.3)$           & HK             &    1.000   &  0.959 &  0.875  &   0.597 &   0.585 &   0.579  &    0.578 &    0.572 \\
                        & HKB            &    1.000   &  0.842 &  0.678  &   0.347 &   0.327 &   0.318  &    0.315 &    0.306 \\
                        & LW             &    1.000   &  0.922 &  0.790  &   0.273 &   0.232 &   0.215  &    0.208 &    0.190 \\
                        & ICOMP          &    1.000   &  0.833 &  0.746  &   0.606 &   0.598 &   0.594  &    0.593 &    0.589 \\
                        & S              &    1.000   &  0.833 &  0.732  &   0.270 &   0.231 &   0.215  &    0.208 &    0.190 \\
                        & GM             &    1.036   &  1.325 &  0.750  &   0.192 &   0.154 &   0.139  &    0.132 &    0.116 \\
                        & AM             & 2043.436   &  6.822 &  2.632  &   0.244 &   0.138 &   0.104  &    0.088 &    0.062 \\
                        & MED            &    1.014   &  1.741 &  0.883  &   0.233 &   0.190 &   0.176  &    0.168 &    0.152 \\
                        & JRR            &    1.000   &  0.982 &  0.912  &   0.627 &   0.608 &   0.599  &    0.596 &    0.587 \\
                        & URR            &    1.000   &  0.725 &  0.515  &   0.250 &   0.236 &   0.231  &    0.231 &    0.229 \\
                        & PCR            &    1.021   &  0.847 &  0.827  &   0.829 &   0.829 &   0.829  &    0.827 &    0.822 \\
                        & PCR CI         &    1.000   &  1.000 &  1.000  &   1.000 &   1.000 &   1.000  &    1.000 &    1.000 \\
                        & R-K            &    1.020   &  0.741 &  0.647  &   0.234 &   0.213 &   0.205  &    0.202 &    0.196 \\
                        & R-K CI         &    1.000   &  0.748 &  0.649  &   0.234 &   0.213 &   0.205  &    0.202 &    0.196 \\
                        & MCRR           &    1.021   &  0.577 &  0.422  &   0.240 &   0.228 &   0.223  &    0.223 &    0.218 \\
                        & MCRR CI        &    1.000   &  0.725 &  0.515  &   0.250 &   0.236 &   0.231  &    0.231 &    0.229 \\
                        & LRRE           &    1.993   &  0.179 &  0.157  &   0.143 &   0.134 &   0.129  &    0.127 &    0.121 \\
                        & LRRE MSE       &    1.042   &  0.535 &  0.519  &   0.514 &   0.510 &   0.504  &    0.502 &    0.493 \\
                        & OIRE           &    5.249   &  1.009 &  0.916  &   0.316 &   0.272 &   0.251  &    0.243 &    0.217 \\
                        & OIRE MSE       &    5.249   &  0.542 &  0.424  &   0.286 &   0.259 &   0.243  &    0.237 &    0.213 \\
                        & GIREI          &    1.000   &  1.058 &  1.022  &   0.407 &   0.341 &   0.305  &    0.290 &    0.253 \\
                        & GIREI MSE      &    1.000   &  0.649 &  0.603  &   0.355 &   0.309 &   0.280  &    0.270 &    0.238 \\
                        & GIREII         &    5.432   &  0.774 &  0.521  &   0.361 &   0.322 &   0.298  &    0.286 &    0.250 \\
                        & GIREII MSE     &    4.496   &  0.562 &  0.422  &   0.341 &   0.308 &   0.285  &    0.275 &    0.240 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I've changed `\tabcolsep` to the maximum value (with two decimals precision) without getting any `Overfull \hbox` warnings.

Comment: really nice answer!!!

Comment: I have to use a special page set up, I didn't post this originally as I didn't think it was relevant. Unfortunately because I am using this special page setup the overfull boxes are still appearing (although there are less of them), I will post up the code showing how the page is set up to the original question. Can you show me how to alter your code so that all the overfull boxes are removed with this alternate page set up?

Answer (score 14):

Your example is far from minimal, but anyway seems like `\midrule` looks ahead and sees `(` so you need

```
\midrule\relax
```

Just as you do to protect cells that start with `[` from `\\` looking ahead.